Views not generated from a PostgreSQL/PostGIS function
I have a "CREATE OR REPLACE" function that runs successfully, but it doesn't generate the views as expected.
The function is used to create the same views in multiple schemas.
i can't understand where the probleme is exactly
I don't find the views in schemas.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.install_views(
    schema_name character varying)
    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE '||quote||'plpgsql'||quote||'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 

AS $BODY$
DECLARE
  schema_name text := quote_ident($1);
  version text := quote_literal('||quote||'1.0.0.1'||quote||');
  quote varchar(1);
BEGIN
  quote := '||quote||''||quote||''||quote||''||quote||';

-- Creation of the first view  
EXECUTE  
'||quote||'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ' || schema_name || '.export_emps_v1
 AS
 SELECT DISTINCT row_number() OVER () AS id,
    emp.id_emprise,
    pro.nom AS nom_projet,
    tel.nom_client::character varying(50) AS "CODE_TEC",
    emp.geom
   FROM ' || schema_name || '.emprise emp
     JOIN ' || schema_name || '.telecom tel ON tel.id_emprise = emp.id_emprise
     JOIN ' || schema_name || '.p_type_telecom ptl ON ptl.id_p_type_telecom = tel.id_p_type_telecom AND ptl.libelle = '||quote||'PM'||quote||'::text
     LEFT JOIN ' || schema_name || '.projet_emprise pno ON pno.id_emprise = emp.id_emprise
     JOIN ' || schema_name || '.projet pro ON pro.id_projet = pno.id_projet;
'||quote||';

-- Creation of the second view 
EXECUTE
'||quote||'
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ' || schema_name || '.view_aer_infra_gc_comp
 AS
 SELECT DISTINCT p.id,
    p.id_lien_infra,
    p.nom_projet,
    (string_to_array(va.commentaire, '||quote||' '||quote||'::text))[2] AS annee,
    p."CODE_POL",
    p."PROPRIO",
    p."TYPE_POS",
    p."CABLE",
    p."LONGUEUR",
    p."ETAT_AVT",
    p.geom
   FROM ' || schema_name || '.export_pol_v1 p
     LEFT JOIN ' || schema_name || '.export_ch_v1 c1 ON st_startpoint(p.geom) = c1.geom AND c1."ETAT_AVT"::text = '||quote||'A REALISER'||quote||'::text AND p."TYPE_INFRA"::text ='||quote||'AERIEN'||quote||'::text
     LEFT JOIN ' || schema_name || '.export_ch_v1 c2 ON st_endpoint(p.geom) = c2.geom AND c2."ETAT_AVT"::text = '||quote||'A REALISER'||quote||'::text AND p."TYPE_INFRA"::text ='||quote||'AERIEN'||quote||'::text
     JOIN ' || schema_name || '.vue_annotation va ON st_within(p.geom, va.geom) AND va.type = '||quote||'COMMENTAIRE BE'||quote||'::text AND (string_to_array(va.commentaire, '||quote||' '||quote||'::text))[1] = '||quote||'COMP'||quote||'::text
  WHERE (c1."ETAT_AVT"::text = '||quote||'A REALISER'||quote||'::text OR c2."ETAT_AVT"::text = '||quote||'A REALISER'||quote||'::text) AND (p."TYPE_INFRA"::text = ANY (ARRAY['||quote||'FACADE'||quote||'::character varying, '||quote||'AERIEN'||quote||'::character varying]::text[]));
'||quote||';

END;
$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION public.install_views(character varying)
    OWNER TO postgres;

The message that the db send is : ALTER FUNCTION
Query returned successfully in 42 msec

You create a function, you don’t execute that function

Yes, you were right, thank you. I am a beginner in SQL.
I still encounter a problem when I run it; it says that the function does not exist in the public schema, even though it does. I execute: SELECT public.install_views();

Your function needs input, the schema name

Hey,
Thank you for your answer you were right, and I found the solution.It was exactly as you told me.
